# How to roll back a SharePoint app

Tags: sharepoint-addin

Can someone tell me what the best approach is to roll back a SharePoint app?

For example, when I have app X and version 1.0.0.0 is in my corporate app catelog. If I now upload version 1.0.0.1 in my corporate app catalog, I'm still able to do a roll back by setting back the previous version of the app.

But what if I already updated the app in all my sites, so all my sites are using version 1.0.0.1 of the app. Is there a way to easily do a rollback of the app back to version 1.0.0.0? Or is the only way creating a new package with version 1.0.0.2 and update again?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Only creating a new package with version 1.0.0.2 and update again is OK. Downgrade is only possible by using a script when you will need to go through all the sites and remove the app (1.0.0.1) and re-add 1.0.0.0 (crazy)

Comment: In similar situation ended up to removing app from site and re-adding it. Bumping up version and running update didn't actually rollback (update) the app properly.